# Jasmine: Controller is defined, but its methods are undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am testing an AngularJS directive's controller.

```
describe('The directive', function() {
    var element,
        scope;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('path/to/theDirective'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        element = angular.element('<div args="args" the-directive ></div>');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.args = {
            availableValues : [1, 2, 3],
            key : 'id',
            selectedValues : [],
            searchText : '',
            flag: false
        };
        scope.$digest();        
    }));

    it('should compile', function() {
        expect(element.html()).not.toBeNull();
    });

    describe('directive controller', function() {
        var controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
            controller = element.controller('theDirective', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it('should exist', function() {
            expect(controller).not.toBeNull();
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
            expect(scope.disableAddButton()).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

The first `it` block passes, so the directive is compiling successfully.  The second `describe` block is not passing.  The first two assertions in the second `describe`'s `it` block pass, but the third one does not.  It's returning `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'scope.disableAddButton()')`.  Is it possible that the controller is not being injected correctly, or is there more setup that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the scope needs to be isolated since the directive's controller is a private function.

Adding `scope = element.isolateScope() || element.scope();` after `scope.$digest();` does the trick.  Also, moving the controller declaration to the first `beforeEach` block isn't a bad idea.

The fixed test would look like this:

```
describe('The directive', function() {
    var element,
        scope,
        theController;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('path/to/theDirective'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        element = angular.element('<div args="args" the-directive ></div>');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.args = {
            availableValues : [1, 2, 3],
            key : 'id',
            selectedValues : [],
            searchText : '',
            flag: false
        };
        scope.$digest();    
        theController = element.controller('theDirective');     
        scope = element.isolateScope() || element.scope();
    }));

    it('should compile', function() {
        expect(element.html()).not.toBeNull();
    });

    describe('directive controller', function() {
        it('should exist', function() {
            expect(theController).not.toBeNull();
            expect(theController).toBeDefined();
            expect(scope.disableAddButton()).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```